# Getting error in SQL query with function use 

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

When I run this query through C# adapter it is causing an error:

> *Incorrect syntax near Use*

Any ideas? When I run this in SQL Server 2008 R2 it's working fine.

```sql
create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split] (@sep nvarchar(10), @s nvarchar(4000))
RETURNS table
AS
  RETURN (
  WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
  SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pn + 1, stop + (datalength(@sep)/2), 
    CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + (datalength(@sep)/2))
  FROM Pieces
  WHERE stop > 0
)
SELECT pn,
SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 4000 END) AS value
FROM Pieces
)
;

/****** Object: Table [dbo].[drillDowntable1] Script Date: 09/24/2012 18:43:32 ******/
USE [master]

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
;
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
;
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[drillDowntable1](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[name] [varchar](20) NULL,
[json] [varchar](max) NULL,
[isActive] [bit] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 5):

You need a `GO` to put things in their own batch.

```sql
FROM Pieces
)
;

GO -- < this is important
/****** Object: Table [dbo].[drillDowntable1] Script Date: 09/24/2012 18:43:32 ******/
USE [master]
```

Comment: I have also done this but after this but its giving me error incorrect syntax near go

Comment: @Rahul well I have no idea which C# adapter you're using to run this script, but if it doesn't understand the GO batch separator, you may have to look into its documentation to see how to correctly terminate batches. You might need to submit each object as its own batch.

Comment: @Rahul - if you're running this from a piece of C#, then you can't use `GO` - but you may still need to split the query, at places you *would* have used `GO`, and run each one in turn as a separate batch.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - You mean by using semicolon ?

Comment: @Rahul no, a semi-colon is a *statement* terminator, not a *batch* separator. Modules like functions need to be in their own *batch*.

Comment: @AaronBertrand : can you please tell me in comment with change  here i m not understanding what you said

Comment: Rahul, just split your script into two parts and run each part on its own.

Comment: still not working There is already an object named 'fn_Split' in the database. getting this error but its not exist in db

Comment: @Rahul are you sure you've set your database context to the right database? Based on what you had I wouldn't be surprised if your database already has that function *and* a copy exists in master too.

Comment: @Rahul well, SQL Server isn't lying to you or playing a joke. Either you aren't checking for the function correctly or you're not in the database you think you are. You can also add IF EXISTS () DROP to the script so it won't matter if a version already exists, but I think you need to straighten out database context first and foremost.