# Error in creating a function in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting error in SQL query with function use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623142/getting-error-in-sql-query-with-function-use)

I get this error when attempting to create a function:

> 'CREATE FUNCTION' must be the first statement in a query batch.
>
> Error:
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.
>
> If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces
>   clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement
>   must be terminated with a semicolon. Must declare the scalar variable
>   "@sep".

This is my T-SQL code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split] (@sep nvarchar(10), @s nvarchar(4000))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
UNION ALL
SELECT pn + 1, stop + (datalength(@sep)/2), CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + (datalength(@sep)/2))
FROM Pieces
WHERE stop > 0
)
SELECT pn,
SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 4000 END) AS value
FROM Pieces
)
;
```

Comment: How, exactly, is this different to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623142/getting-error-in-sql-query-with-function-use)?

Comment: It's not just "related to previous" - it's exactly the same question. And you've not even bothered to include any of the useful information that was painstakingly gleaned from you then (i.e. that this isn't a script being run from management studio, that you're running this code from a C# application)

Comment: As a convenience to seekers, is it possible to include a link to the previous question in the marked as duplicate message box? Damien was kind enough to include the link in his comments, but this isn't a consistent practice.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't define table structure in return type

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split] (@sep nvarchar(10), @s nvarchar(4000))
RETURNS table TABLE (pn varcahr(100), values varchar(8000))  
AS
RETURN (
WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
UNION ALL
SELECT pn + 1, stop + (datalength(@sep)/2), CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + (datalength(@sep)/2))
FROM Pieces
WHERE stop > 0
)     SELECT pn,
  SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 4000 END) AS value
 FROM Pieces
)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a GO between USE AppName and the create statement

Something like

```
Use AppName    
GO

create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split] (@sep nvarchar(10), @s nvarchar(4000)) 
RETURNS table 
AS 
RETURN ( 
WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS ( 
SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT pn + 1, stop + (datalength(@sep)/2), CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + (datalength(@sep)/2)) 
FROM Pieces 
WHERE stop > 0 
) 
SELECT pn, 
SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 4000 END) AS value 
FROM Pieces 
) 
;
```

Comment: The problem is (as you'll shortly find out, or if you look at their previous question) that they're not running this through SSMS or a SQL command line tool, so `GO` isn't available. They've previously been told that they need to separate batches themselves. I'm not sure why this new question has been asked.

Comment: but using GO does not support in C sharp so i can't use it.when i use it gives error incorrect syntax near GO ...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever now i m running it in different batches ...

Comment: @Rahul - and we can tell that *how*, exactly, from your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
better than you will use procedure :
CREATE procedure [dbo].[fn_Split] 
@sep nvarchar(10),
@s nvarchar(4000))
AS
begin
  your logic..
  select col,.. from table;
end
```

Comment: Who upvotes this stuff? A TVF is far better as a split function because it is more versatile. You can join on it or add a where clause when selecting from it for example.

Answer (score 0):

I got Solution for this

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;



SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(query);                
conn.Close();
```

Now i can run with Go Statement in SQL query...